# RAM compatibility issues with Intel motherboard

Tags: memory

I have a computer with an ASUS C422 SAGE 10G motherboard and a Xeon W-2125 CPU.  It has 4 Kingston 16 GB DIMMS with ECC installed.  Recently, I wanted to upgrade the memory, and ordered 4 new 32 GB DIMMS, also with ECC.  But these are not detected by the system at all, the BIOS shows 64 GB memory, and Linux likewise shows the slots as empty (from `dmidecode`).

The only notable differences I can find is that the old DIMMS are 2666MHz, the new ones are 3200 - but I would have thought the MB would just downclock it?  The old ones are further marked 1Rx8, the new ones 2Rx8 - does that make a difference?

Any ideas?  The documentation for the mainboard only talks about supported sizes, which go up to 128 GB, and does not go into details that would explain the incompatibility.

Comment: Did you try to only run the new ones? And also test one at a time?

Comment: Yes, no boot.  I didn't try each one of the new ones alone, but I tried various configurations.

Comment: So be systematic, first try the old ones and see which configuration that works, then retry the same previously working configuration but with new sticks. A good thing is to work with the assumption that one or more of the new ones are bad, and you need to figure out which ones. Until you have confirmed them working in this system or other, it might as well be that they are all bad.